# Linq ForEach with AddRange and Contains And Select

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, foreach

i am having a foreach loop that i am trying to turn into a linq query

```
List<CustomType> typeList=new List<CustomType>();
List<int> ListID=new List<int>();

foreach (Info info in SubDetails)
{
    if (typeList.Contains(info.TypeID))
    {
        ListID.Add(info.OrderID);
    }
}
```

Now i am trying to turn it into a linq loop

```
 SubDetails.ForEach(u => List.AddRange(
                    typeList.Contains(ID or something)
                    .Select(u.OrderID)));
```

But that did not work obviously, Kindly guide me towards the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var ListID = SubDetails
                .Where(info => typeList.Any(type => type == info.TypeID)
                .Select(info => info.OrderID);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fill up ListID as

```
SubDetails.Where(t => typeList.Exists(lst => lst.XXX == t.TypeID)).Select(id => id.OrderID)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, but i am getting the error from typeList.Contains(t.TypeID)) as typeList.Contains expect something of Custom type in it, i could make it work my merging with answer of Ed, typeList.Any(u=>u.TypeID==t.TypeID), kindly enlighten your approach

Comment: Oops i missed the customtype part

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
var ListID = typelist.Join(SubDetails,tl=>tl,sd=>sd.TypeID,(tl,sd)=>sd.OrderID).ToArray();
```